# Unicorn sync __Security for new items only synchronisation existing items

Tags: unicorn, permissions

My Problem is, I've some configuration Items which are created with the new Items Only sync. That seems to work.

But when I add some roles/permissions to this Items on my local dev machine and I want to sync them also on my staging environment, then the new roles/permissions never get applied to this existing items. I think this is right.

But how can I handle permission changes on new Items Only synced items with Unicorn, when I change or Add permissions to new Items Only synced items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... you can't.

`NewItemsOnly` does as the name would indicate. It syncs only items onto your target environment that do not already exist.

One thing you could do, was to apply permissions on a parent item to the item in questions, one which you had under normal Unicorn control. And manage permissions on that, having them be inherited to child items.

Comment: how do you manage your Rights in the Content tree with unicorn? Do you set your rights manually on each stage?

Comment: Unicorn isn't really designed to manage items in the Content Tree, is the short answer. But if anything, I would assign roles to my items and then manage it through role membership.